# Append element with name attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I've created a radio button using java script and now i want to append it in a row of a table using name attribute. there are multiple rows in a table.
thanks in advance.....
my code is-

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
var newCol = document.createElement("td");
var newInput = document.createElement("input");
newInput.type="radio";
newCol.appendChild(newInput);
newRow.appendChild(newCol);
```

Comment: You should show your markup to give us an idea of where you want the input to appear in the table

Comment: please show some more details !!!

Comment: Do you have a *specific* problem? Possibly even a **question**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using **getElementsByName**, as shown below.

```
var table = document.getElementsByName("myTableName")[0];
var row = table.insertRow(0);
var cell = row.insertCell(0);

var newInput = document.createElement("input");
newInput.type="radio";

cell.appendChild(newInput);
```